# How to access WPF class library from Silverlight using iron python. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, silverlight, ironpython

I'm having a class library. I'm able to access that assembly from iron python console as normal.

My goal is to create a Silverlight class library which uses a python script to access that WPF class library what I'm having. Is it possible? Is there any other way to achieve this or any work around.

I can provide a sample of what I'm doing now, If more details are needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to use the class library unless its code is compatible with Silverlight libraries and is re-compiled targeting the Silverlight ones.