# Sharing assembly code between WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone: quite impractical for big projects !

Tags: wpf, silverlight

It is said here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/writing-cross-platform-xaml-applications.aspx

Within Visual Studio, if you add files to the project via “Add Existing Item”, and select the “Add As Link” option you can work on the same file from multiple projects.

Oh my I'm on a project which have multiple countries, brands, components layers and each time I will add a file you want me to "Add as Link" ? This is a nightmare maintenance !

Is there any other solutions ?

Comment: Attention searchers!  Check out [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx), now supported in .NET 4.0!

Answer (score 2):

How about making a new assembly (or a few) out of the shared things and referencing them from all your projects, instead of adding the files themselves as links?

Comment: Exactly, using linked files seems like a management nightmare.  Also, it can be helpful to add the library assembly to the solution so you can step through that code while debugging.

Comment: Can compiled assemblies be shared between WPF Silverlight and WP7 ? as far as I know It can't maybe am I wrong ?

Comment: @user310291 Compiled assemblies can never be shared. Once before I attempted it. No use at all. Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251296/how-to-access-wpf-class-library-from-silverlight-using-iron-python-is-it-possibl